# Summarising diagrams for layer

Tags: qgis, diagram

I wonder if there is a possibility (plugin etc.) to create a summarising diagram of attributes more or less comparable to the summarising statistics. e.g. having a shape with a high number of polygons of different landuse attributes and want to create a diagram with the sum of area for the different land use types as a bar chart or pie chart diagram. x axes land use types, y axes sum of area.

Comment: I found already a tool in the processing toolbox "graphics, bar plot" but this obviously is not summing up the ha to one bar but instead plot all values on top of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the 'DataPlotly' plugin which solves everthing perfectly.
With it you can choose the plot type e.g. bar plot, define the x and y axes parameters. In the settings you are also able to choose the bar mode. The bar mode 'stacked' is summing up the values. However, there are some problems to visualise the charts e.g. the axes titles can´t be adapted properly if needed. There should be a link to edit the charts in the chart studio (button at the top of the chart see picture) but this functionallity is deactivated and greyed out. All in all it provides a fast overview. 
[image]

Comment: This is quite a short answer, perhaps you could enrich it with some further information how dataplotly plugin solved your issues, screenshots, results and so on.

Comment: Well done! This explains your approach perfectly!